# How to load data use less memory in BigQuery & Python

Tags: python, memory, google-bigquery

Is there Anyone use **BigQuery** like this?

I Found Something weird.

Here are 2 examples.

**EX 1)**

```
select var1, var2
from table
```

**EX 2)**

```
select strct(var1, var2) as var
from table
```

these are come out same result but in Python different.

I don't know why df, df2 use different memory size.

[image]

Comment: I might be wrong, but is it because example 2 querying 1 column and example 1 querying 2 columns?

Comment: I understand from the title that you're trying to load data in BigQuery using Python, but the examples that you shared are two SELECT statements, do you mind sharing your script along with the client library version used?  Once we have your script we'll be able to debug what's causing the difference memory size.

Comment: thanks. here is my sample Query. please check.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PldimfB5XDE6QMKE0Ejb4_qjygUnODZvdpbFTzXt4wY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I used your provided sample query and created a table using the information you provided. I used this script to attempt a recreation:

```
def query_stackoverflow():
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = """
    select date, 
    userid, struct(price, code) as struced_var
    FROM `projectid.dataset.table`
"""
    df = client.query(query_job).to_dataframe()
    print(df)
    print(df.memory_usage())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    query_stackoverflow()
```

And my output was:

```
        date  userid                 struced_var
0  2020-01-07       1  {'price': 10, 'code': 100}
1  2020-01-07       1  {'price': 10, 'code': 100}
2  2020-01-07       1  {'price': 10, 'code': 100}
3  2020-01-07       1  {'price': 10, 'code': 100}
4  2020-01-07       1  {'price': 10, 'code': 100}
5  2020-01-07       1  {'price': 10, 'code': 100}
6  2020-01-07       1  {'price': 10, 'code': 100}
7  2020-01-07       1  {'price': 10, 'code': 100}
8  2020-01-07       1  {'price': 10, 'code': 100}
9  2020-01-07       1  {'price': 10, 'code': 100}

Index          128
date            80
userid          80
struced_var     80
dtype: int64
```

I also tried the same query without the struct. And my output was:

```
        date  userid  price  code
0  2020-01-07       1     10   100
1  2020-01-07       1     10   100
2  2020-01-07       1     10   100
3  2020-01-07       1     10   100
4  2020-01-07       1     10   100
5  2020-01-07       1     10   100
6  2020-01-07       1     10   100
7  2020-01-07       1     10   100
8  2020-01-07       1     10   100
9  2020-01-07       1     10   100

Index     128
date       80
userid     80
price      80
code       80
dtype: int64
```

To conclude, everything is working as intended. When I use the struct within the query, the memory_usage returned 1 fewer column than when I did not use the struct. This is due to the struct combining the price and code columns. So with the struct, we see 3 columns within memory_usage and without struct we see 4 columns.

I am still not sure why your query has multiple columns missing but this recreation makes me think it might be due to the struct combining multiple columns of your query and returning fewer columns within your memory_usage. Either way it doesn't show how you're loading data into BigQuery.